# Downloading file via AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm using AJAX to submit a `POST` request to my Rails controller

```
$("#submit_form").submit(function(event) {
  ...
  /* Send the data using post*/
    $.post( "/download", { s: term },
      function( data ) {}
    );
});
```

The controller returns a file using the Rails `send_file` method. However, when I click on the form button, no file is downloaded to me, even though the response header says

```
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="pic.jpg"
```

How can I get the file?

Comment: Why do you want to use an AJAX request to download a file rather than a normal POST request? The will still remain on the page with a normal POST request.

Comment: Ah, very good point, David! You're right. I forgot to think about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's AFAIK not possible to let users download files using AJAX requests and I see no reason to do it that way, since the user will remain on the page when downloading a file.

For a file to be downloaded, the response must be handled by the web browser rather than your JavaScript code.